# GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE error when I try to set a geofence area

Tags: android, geofencing, geofire, android-geofence, geofirestore

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong, when I press on the screen I want to set a geofence area, I can see on the screen that the are is created but I'm getting and error that "GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE".

ON my app setting the app has location permission;

Maps.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private GeofencingClient geofencingClient;
    private GeofenceHelper geofenceHelper;

    private int FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE = 10001;

    private float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 200;

    private String GEOFENCE_ID = "SOMEID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
        geofenceHelper   = new GeofenceHelper(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng office = new LatLng(33.822, -116.5379);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(office, 16));

        enableUserLocation();
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    private void enableUserLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
        mMap.clear();
        addMarker(latLng);
        addCircle(latLng, GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
        addGeofence(latLng, GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
    }

    private void addGeofence(LatLng latLng, float radius) {
        Geofence geofence = geofenceHelper.getGeofence(GEOFENCE_ID, latLng, radius, Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);
        GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = geofenceHelper.geofencingRequest(geofence);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = geofenceHelper.getPendingIntent();
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, pendingIntent).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Geocende added");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                String errorMessage = geofenceHelper.getErrorString(e);
                Log.e("TAG", "onFailure: " + errorMessage);
            }
        });
    }

    private void addMarker(LatLng latLng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    private void addCircle(LatLng latLng, float radius) {
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
        circleOptions.center(latLng);
        circleOptions.radius(radius);
        circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));
        circleOptions.fillColor(Color.argb(64, 255, 0, 0));
        circleOptions.strokeColor(4);
        mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    }
}
```

GeofenceHelper.java

```
public class GeofenceHelper extends ContextWrapper {

    private static final String TAG = "GeofenceHelper";
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    public GeofenceHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest (Geofence geofence) {
        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .addGeofence(geofence)
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                .build();
    }

    public Geofence getGeofence(String ID, LatLng latLng, float radius, int transitionTypes) {
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setCircularRegion(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, radius)
                .setRequestId(ID)
                .setTransitionTypes(transitionTypes)
                .setLoiteringDelay(5000)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .build();
    }

    public PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {

        if (pendingIntent != null) {
            return pendingIntent;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2607, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        return pendingIntent;
    }

    public String getErrorString(Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ApiException) {
            ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
            switch (apiException.getStatusCode()) {
                case GeofenceStatusCodes
                        .GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                    return "GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE";
                case GeofenceStatusCodes
                        .GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                    return "GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES";
                case GeofenceStatusCodes
                        .GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                    return "GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS";
            }
        }

        return e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }

}
```

GoefenceBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        Toast.makeText(context, "Geofence trigerred...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```